# What's happening when the special variable is declared during compile time

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, dynamic-binding

I just met an unusual situation in my common lisp code when I wanna test `locally` and `declare`:

```lisp
(defvar test-out 2) ;; make a dynamic variable

;; function below just simply re-write from locally doc
(defun test (out)
  (declare (special out))
  (let ((out 1))
    (print out) ;; => 1
    (print (locally (declare (special out)) out)))) ;; => 2

;; when argument has same name as outside dynamic variable
(defun test1 (test-out)
  (declare (special test-out))
  (let ((test-out 1))
    (print test-out) ;; => 1
    (print (locally (declare (special test-out)) test-out)))) ;; => also 1
```

I know the right name of dynamic variable should be `*test-out*`, but I thought it just for programmer to tell dynamic variable conveniently.

I am a bit confuse about `test1` function, it looks like `locally declare` do not point `test-out` to dynamic variable outside.

Can anyone explain to me `test1` function's behavior? Thanks

**Update:**

1. I give a new dynamic variable `(defvar test-out-1 3)`, and call it like `(test1 test-out-1)`, still get print out result `1` and `1`.
2. I change `test1`'s argument name from `test-out` to `test-out1`, recompile `test1`, and problem disappears, print out results are `1` and `2` when I call `(test1 test-out)`.
3. I change `(defvar test-out 2)` to `(defvar test-out-1 2)` (change dynamic variable name). Then recompile whole file (no dynamic variable called `test-out` this time, and `test1` argument's name is `test-out`), problem disappears.
4. **After 3**, I call `(defvar test-out 2)`, and `(test1 test-out)`. This time, it prints out right answers: `1` and `2`.
5. **After 4**, I recompile `test1` again, then run `(test1 test-out)`, it prints out `1` and `1` again, problem appears again.

If I guess right, when `test1` compiling, for some reason, its arguments' name connect to dynamic variable `test-out`. That's why I receiving wrong result when I even call with different value, however, problem is solved by itself when I recompile `test1` with different argument name or clean dynamic variable `test-out` before recompile test.

If so, I still do not understand why compile function will effect by dynamic variable in the environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DEFVAR` declares a variable to be *special* - that means they will use dynamic bindings when bound and access to such a variable will look for dynamic bindings. Globally and on all binding levels. For now and in the future.

From then on, *ALL* uses and bindings of that variable in new code will be declared special automatically. Even local LET bindings. On all levels. There is no way to declare it *unspecial*. Thus a local special declaration in your `test1` function now is not needed, it already is declared special. Every use or binding of it, even without explicit declaration is now using dynamic binding.

That's also the reason why any `DEFVAR` or `DEFPARAMETER` variable should be written as `*variablename*`, to prevent accidentally declaring all variables with the same name to be special.

Avoid:

```
(defvar x 10)         ; here X is explicitly declared special

(defun foo (x)        ; here X is implicitly declared special
  (let ((x ...))      ; here X is implicitly declared special
    ...))
```

Do:

```
(defvar *x* 10)       ; here *X* is declared special

(defun foo (x)        ; here X is lexical
  (let ((x ...))      ; here X is lexical
    ...))
```

Comment: So, for my **Update 4**, `(defvar test-out 2)` after `test1` compiled won't effect `test1` because it already compiled?

Comment: @ccQpein: right, a DEFVAR usually would not have effect on earlier compiled code. If earlier compiled code was compiled to use lexical binding, this will not be changed later when a DEFVAR gets compiled/load/executed.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig, Wouldn't it also be acceptable to do: `(defvar *x* 10) (defun foo () (let ((*x* ...)) ...))`